# Play 2 framework unit tests - java.lang.RuntimeException: DataSource user is null?

Tags: unit-testing, playframework, playframework-2.0, h2, ebean

I trying to run unit tests in Play 2 application using H2 database in MySQL compatibility mode. I configured it in `@Before` as follow:

```java
@Before
public void startApp() throws Exception {
    Map<String, String> settings = new HashMap<String, String>();
    settings.put("db.default.driver", "org.h2.Driver");
    settings.put("db.default.user", "sa");
    settings.put("db.default.password", "");
    settings.put("db.default.url", "jdbc:h2:mem:play-test-351881363;MODE=MySQL"); // TODO: use config for url
    settings.put("db.default.jndiName", "DefaultDS");
    app = Helpers.fakeApplication(settings);
    Helpers.start(app);

    databaseTester = new JndiDatabaseTester("DefaultDS");

    IDataSet expectedDataSet = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(play.Play.application()
            .resourceAsStream("/resources/dataset.xml"));
    databaseTester.setDataSet(expectedDataSet);
    databaseTester.onSetup();
}

@After
public void stopApp() throws Exception {
    databaseTester.onTearDown();
    Helpers.stop(app);
}
```

But it results in `java.lang.RuntimeException: DataSource user is null?` in actual test method when it tries to access database:

```
[ERROR] [02/12/2013 01:19:32.085] [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://application/user/load_data_task_runner_test/load_record] DataSource user is null?
java.lang.RuntimeException: DataSource user is null?
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.sql.DataSourcePool.<init>(DataSourcePool.java:184)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.sql.DataSourceManager.getDataSource(DataSourceManager.java:200)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.sql.DataSourceGlobalManager.getDataSource(DataSourceGlobalManager.java:46)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.getDataSourceFromConfig(DefaultServerFactory.java:432)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.setDataSource(DefaultServerFactory.java:393)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.createServer(DefaultServerFactory.java:169)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.createServer(DefaultServerFactory.java:124)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.createServer(DefaultServerFactory.java:64)
    at com.avaje.ebean.EbeanServerFactory.create(EbeanServerFactory.java:45)
    at com.avaje.ebean.Ebean$ServerManager.getWithCreate(Ebean.java:206)
    at com.avaje.ebean.Ebean$ServerManager.get(Ebean.java:193)
    at com.avaje.ebean.Ebean$ServerManager.access$200(Ebean.java:128)
    at com.avaje.ebean.Ebean.getServer(Ebean.java:257)
    at play.db.ebean.Model$Finder.server(Model.java:240)
    at play.db.ebean.Model$Finder.byId(Model.java:261)
    at integration.LoadRecordService.onReceive(LoadRecordService.java:50)
    at akka.actor.UntypedActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(UntypedActor.scala:159)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:425)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:386)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:230)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:212)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$MailboxExecutionTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:502)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:262)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:975)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1478)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
```

Here evolutions and initialization using [dbunit](http://www.dbunit.org/) work in `startApp()`, exception is thrown in a `@Test` method.

What I am doing wrong?

P.S. I am not using `play.test.Helpers.running` because it takes `Runnable` as parameter and `run()` in runnable cannot throw exceptions. So to catch exceptions in unit test I must wrap entire `run()` into `try`, catch exceptions, fail unittest and log message manually. It bloats code a lot. Here is code of `running()`:

```java
public static synchronized void running(FakeApplication fakeApplication, final Runnable block) {
    try {
        start(fakeApplication);
        block.run();
    } finally {
        stop(fakeApplication);
    }
}
```

I do the same in my `@Before` and `@After`, maybe except some threading stuff that may be cause of errors.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Problem was caused by `ebean.default` key in config was commented out in main config:

```
ebean.default="models.*"
```

And setting user and password for H2 is *not* necessarry, it works without it:

```
settings.put("db.default.user", "sa");
settings.put("db.default.password", "");
```